# $cookies is lost after page refreshing

Tags: angularjs, cookies, refresh, ajax-request

I try to save login's informations in a cookie. After my method, the cookies is registered with good datas. But, when I redirect to the next page, the cookie is lost. I don't understand why. If someone can explain me.

This is my login method:

```
 $scope.Login = function()
    {
        var expireDateCookies = new Date();

        expireDateCookies.setHours(expireDateCookies.getHours() + 6);


        // default post header to url encoded content
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';

        //variable who contains the authentication information
        var auth = $scope.auth;

        var requestGetToken = $http({ method: 'POST', url: url, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }, data: $.param({ username: auth.Login, password: auth.Password, grant_type: 'password', client_id: client_id }) });
        requestGetToken.success(function (data) {
            $cookieStore.put('access_token', data.access_token, { 'expires': expireDateCookies });
        });
        // default post header to json
        $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        $window.location.href = '/CustomersList';
    }
```

Thank you for all the help you could give me.

Comment: Looks like $cookieStore.put() doesn't allow for a third parameter...
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngCookies/cookieStore.js#L4

Answer (score 0):

Hey just wished to let you know, the $cookieStore is depricated now. Please check the [angular documentation for the same](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore).
[image]

Trying using the [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) instead. May be that's a reason for why you are facing the cookies clearing issue.

Just adding to this info, you can also go for [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) an HTML 5 feature that allows you to store data as key-value pairs in the browser itself. It has no expiry period.